# Struts 2 validation - clearing the error message

Tags: validation, struts2

Good day!

I used the Struts2 xml validation as instructed in [this website](http://java.dzone.com/articles/struts2-tutorial-part-37).

The problem is when I clicked the submit button twice. The error message also appears twice...

My question is... how to clear the first error message before another action is processed to accommodate new set of error messages.

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did your application integrate with Spring?

Comment: Error messages usually only exist for request scope. So error messages don't need to be cleared.  You'll need to provide more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a validator interceptor in the default stack. You just need to use that and using that is very simple. Just make a method in your action class by the name public void validate(). Within that validate() you can access the fields using their getters & then put the required validation onto them.

Also, with this implementation you would not have to worry about the multiple messages being shown, because it will show only the message what you set in the addFieldError method and removes any previously kept messages.

NOTE: Be sure to use getters of the variables in your validate(), because the variables in the action are not set at the time this interceptor is invoked.

Here is a link to a very nice tutorial.

http://www.vaannila.com/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-validation-example-1.html

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the spring integration you have to define your bean as `scope="prototype"`, then you get a new instance of your Action for every request.
The default scope for spring is singleton.

It's a good idea to do this for every Action.

Comment: Why not `scope="request"` ?

Comment: When I answered this Question 7 years ago, there only was `prototype` or `singleton`. Maybe nowadays `request` is the best.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `validate="true"` from form tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you will keep validate=false, then validation xml will be called on submit action.

To clear messages on each submit click, if you are using table in your jsp then keep table outside of form. It will work.